# Smartadmin, Bootstrap 3 buttons with span have dead poin. Does not fire the event

Tags: css, events, click, twitter-bootstrap-3

Everyone I have really strange issue, I cant provide a jsfiddle because when I test there the problem does not appear. I just wondering if somebody face the same issue and can help me. So I use SmartAdmin template which is based on bootstrap 3, the problem is that when I add `<a href="javascript:test();" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>Add Contact</span></a>` there is a dead line where the click event does not work, Here is a picture

[image]

on that green line rigth after the span element the click event is not attached, I've tried without span and works ok, but I need that span to be there, I add some padding to that span and margin, but that line is still there on the same position 1px after the element which is in `<a></a>`. Just to let you know about I've tried with `href="javascript:test();"` and with `$(document).on();`  Thanks for any suggestions in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just overlapping the span with the anchor, I tried this and the click event stopped working:

WON'T WORK

```
<a href="javascript:alert('ok');" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span    style="padding:5px; margin-left: 5px;">Add Contact</span></a>
```

JUST padding-left not padding-bottom - WORKS!

```
<a href="javascript:alert('ok');" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span style="padding-left:5px; margin-left: 5px;">Add Contact</span></a>
```

Here's a snapshot of that:
(I can't post images yet, so here's the url)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjDUw.png